# How to split a column into two and keep the same header?

Tags: python, pandas, split

I want to split each of the columns of a dataframe at space while keep the same header for each splitted column.

Is there anyway that I could do that?

Input:

```
ID<tab>Sample1<tab>Sample2<tab>Sample3
123<tab>x y<tab>z k<tab>a r
234<tab>j y<tab>v w<tab>f d
345<tab>h s<tab>s b<tab>w a
```

Output

```
ID<tab>Sample1<tab>Sample1<tab>Sample2<tab>Sample2<tab>Sample3<tab>Sample3
123<tab>x<tab>y<tab>z<tab>k<tab>a<tab>r
234<tab>j<tab>y<tab>v<tab>w<tab>f<tab>d
345<tab>h<tab>s<tab>s<tab>b<tab>w<tab>a
```

Comment: why keep the same name , since pandas is index and column base data structure , if you have same name for multiple columns  most of the build-in function will not work

Comment: Do you want to go via a pandas dataframe or produce one, or do you just want to convert formatted text as shown? And do you know in advance how many columns there will be or how many sub-columns within each column (e.g., two)? Will each row have the same number of sub-columns for each column (e.g., if the first row has two entries for Sample1, will all the other rows also have two?)? If not, how do you want to fill the missing values?

Comment: @WeNYoBen I want to keep the same name because I want to fit everything into a regression model. But each sample has two subcolumns (2 x values) when they map to the same y value. So I thought keeping the same column header would be a good idea?

Comment: @MatthiasFripp Yes, I doesn't have to be in pandas. There are around 400 columns and each one has exactly 2 subcolumns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are always two sub-columns per column, then you can use something like this. I recommend tagging each column with a unique key, since you will need unique names when you do regressions. But you can leave the tag off if you want.

```
orig = """ID<tab>Sample1<tab>Sample2<tab>Sample3
123<tab>x y<tab>z k<tab>a r
234<tab>j y<tab>v w<tab>f d
345<tab>h s<tab>s b<tab>w a""".replace("<tab>", "\t")

header, body = orig.split("\n", 1)

# Create new headers with _0 and _1 tags.
# You can leave out the "_{}" to avoid adding the tags
headers = header.split('\t')
new_headers = (
    [headers[0]]
    + ["{}_{}".format(h, i) for h in headers for i in range(2)]
)
new_header = "\t".join(new_headers)

# convert the body and reassemble
new = new_header + "\n" + body.replace(" ", "\t")

print(new.replace("\t", "<tab>"))

# ID<tab>ID_0<tab>ID_1<tab>Sample1_0<tab>Sample1_1<tab>Sample2_0<tab>Sample2_1<tab>Sample3_0<tab>Sample3_1
# 123<tab>x<tab>y<tab>z<tab>k<tab>a<tab>r
# 234<tab>j<tab>y<tab>v<tab>w<tab>f<tab>d
# 345<tab>h<tab>s<tab>s<tab>b<tab>w<tab>a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by two chains. Once for the values and once for the columns:

`pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda row: list(chain.from_iterable(row.apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')))), axis=1).values.tolist(), columns=list(chain.from_iterable((col, col) for col in df.columns)))`